# What are "Metro apps"?

Tags: windows, windows-8, metro

While it is relatively new now (2011/09/15), are there any resources for explanations of Metro applications for Windows8?

I've not seen anything at the moment that summarises an "elevator pitch" for them.

Comment: Give it about a year then ask again...

Comment: I don't think this is too localised, people will be completely ignorant of whether it is MS specific until they have been introduced to it; which is the point of this question.

Comment: hmmm #agedLikeMilk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [my extensive answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244834/what-will-the-future-be-for-wpf-and-silverlight-under-windows-8/7416361#7416361).

There are plenty of relevant sources available indicating their 'elevator pitch', and new information is made available at a regular interval on the [BUILD blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/).

The article which will probably interest you the most talks about ['Designing for Metro style and the desktop'](https://web.archive.org/web/20151021005804/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2011/08/31/designing-for-metro-style-and-the-desktop.aspx).

If you have time to watch it, I got a good impression of where they want to head to from watching the [keynote of the BUILD conference](https://mybuild.microsoft.com/).

For immediate hands-on experience you can download the [developer preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/).

Comment: If only Visual Studio 11 on the preview in a VM on a Q6600 would take less than 5 minutes to compile, deploy and run a Metro 'Hello World', I might be tempted to do more with it. *8')

Answer (score 2):

From: http://dougseven.com/2011/09/14/i-know-what-youre-thinking-and-youre-wrong/ (A Telerik Executive VP's blog).

> Metro style apps are intended to be touch centric, sensor aware, single screen apps that will likely run on smaller form factors more often than a desktop or laptop PC (in fact we were thinking about calling these apps ‘NISA apps’ – Natural Interface, Sensor Aware apps….we canned that idea).